# Azure webapp deployment docker container not responding to HTTP pings

Tags: django, azure, docker

I am trying to deploy a Django application using Azure Linux WebApp.

Looking at the deployment logs for my application itself shows no errors. But there are errors in the Docker logs:

```
ERROR - Container xxx for site xxx has exited, failing site start
ERROR - Container xxx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

I am not familiar with Docker containers and I don't have access to the config file for it. I've tried setting `PORT`, `WEBSITE_PORT`, `WEBSITES_PORT` to `8000` in my Azure application settings but this did not work. Does anybody has some suggestions for how to fix this error?

Comment: How do you deploy your application to Azure Web App? Do you use the image? Can you share the Dockerfile?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it as the answer. Or give the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy the application to Azure Linux WebApp, you need to create your custom image or the build-in images and then there are two different situations.

One is that deploy a single container to Web App. Then Web App will automatic to detect the port which exposed in the image and then you can access the application through the Internet after it runs well.

The other one is that when deploys multiple containers to Web App, it will detect the container that named web or first container to decide which port to expose to outside. Or you can use the environment variable `WEBSITES_PORT` to expose the port which your application listened to.

So first, you need to check if your image can run well locally, then you can choose which way you need to use according to the situation in which you are. For more details about the error, see [Your container must respond to an HTTP ping](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NoPing).

Comment: I have same problem, and adding WEBSITES_PORT does not help